# Можно ли следующим образом заменить if-else блок на try-catch блок?

Tags: c#

Можно ли следующим образом заменить if-else блок на try-catch блок?

```
    String updateScriptPath = compileUpdateScript(inputVersion, searchPath);
    if (updateScriptPath == null)
    {
       Console.WriteLine("  No update sripts found  :( ");
    }
    else
    {
       Console.WriteLine(updateScriptPath); 
    }



    String updateScriptPath = compileUpdateScript(inputVersion, searchPath);
    try
    {   
        Console.WriteLine(updateScriptPath); 
    }
    catch
    { 
         Console.WriteLine("  No scripts found :( ");
    }
```

Comment: - Нет, не имеет.

Comment: а что, при подаче `null` в `Console.WriteLine` возникает исключение?

Comment: try catch - для исключений, второй ваш пример проверка null через try-catch как то не в тему

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Можно, но:

- Во-первых, поведение будет не совсем одинаковое. При вызове `Console.WriteLine()` с `null` в качестве параметра будет выведена [пустая строка](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/swx4tc5e%28v=vs.110%29.aspx). Т.е. c `if` всегда выводится только одна строка, а в случае с `try/catch` может быть выведено две строки.
- Во-вторых, даже если бы вызов `Console.WriteLine()` с `null` в качестве параметра приводил к исключению, использовать `try/catch` для проверок -- дурной тон. Если есть возможность сделать проверку заранее, нужно всегда делать ее заранее. Подробнее почитать о правильном использовании `try/catch`, можно [тут](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/446029/%D0%93%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BC%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B5-%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%B7%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5-try-catch). А также тонкости использование и сравнение c `if` обсуждали [тут](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/558472/) и [тут](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/299080/).

Comment: «использовать try/catch для проверок -- дурной тон» — с каких пор и в каком обществе?

Comment: @ixSci ладно, возможно это я преувеличил :). Но если есть возможность сделать проверку -- лучше сделать проверку. Буду рад контрпримерам.

Comment: Вы знаете, я честно говоря не могу придумать пример, где такая смесь вообще возможна. Разумеется, если из функции может быть возвращён null, то его необходимо проверять, а не ждать null exception. Просто случай в вопросе где-то на гране клинического, поэтому его вообще нет смысла обсуждать, как мне кажется. Я же немного про другое: к примеру Parse/TryParse — выбор того или иного варианта далеко не очевиден и, в зависимости от задачи и предпочтений, может быть выбран любой из них. Т.е. нет правильного пути, поэтому нет и «дурного тона»

Answer (score 1):

Нельзя, `try` в вашем случае относится к попытке вывести в `Console`, а не к результатам `compileUpdateScript`.